# python error when finding count of cells where value was found

Tags: python, string, pandas, contains

I have below code on toy data which works the day i want. Last 2 columns provide how many times value in column `Jan` was found in column `URL` and in how many distinct rows value in column `Jan` was found in column `URL`

```
sales = [{'account': '3', 'Jan': 'xxx', 'Feb': '200 .jones', 'URL': 'ea2018-001.pdf try bbbbb why try'},
             {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'try', 'Feb': '210', 'URL': ''},
             {'account': '2',  'Jan': 'bbbbb',  'Feb': '90',  'URL': 'ea2017-104.pdf bbbbb cc for why try' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

df['found_in_column'] = df['Jan'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(df['URL'].tolist()).count(x))
df['distinct_finds'] = df['Jan'].apply(lambda x: sum(df['URL'].str.contains(x)))
```

why does the same code fails in the last case? How could i change my code to avoid the error. In case of my last example there are special characters in the first column, I felt that they are causing the problem. But when i look at row where index is 3 and 4, they have special characters too and code runs fine

```
answer2=answer[['Value','non_repeat_pdf']].iloc[0:11]


print(answer2)

            Value                                     non_repeat_pdf
0     effect\nive    Initials: __\nDL_  -1- Date: __\n8/14/2017\n...
1         closing                                               @@@@
2       executing                                               @@@@
3          order,                                               @@@@
4         waives:                                               @@@@
5           right                                               @@@@
6          notice                                               @@@@
7       intention                                               @@@@
8        prohibit                                               @@@@
9         further                                               @@@@
10  participation                                               @@@@

answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: sum(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].str.contains(x)))

Out[220]: 
0     1
1     0
2     1
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     0
10    0
Name: Value, dtype: int64

answer2=answer[['Value','non_repeat_pdf']].iloc[10:11]


print(answer2)

            Value non_repeat_pdf
10  participation           @@@@

answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: sum(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].str.contains(x)))

Out[212]: 
10    0
Name: Value, dtype: int64

answer2=answer[['Value','non_repeat_pdf']].iloc[11:12]


print(answer2)

       Value non_repeat_pdf
11  1818(e);           @@@@

answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: sum(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].str.contains(x)))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-215-2df7f4b2de41>", line 1, in <module>
    answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: sum(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].str.contains(x)))

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2355, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1574, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

  File "<ipython-input-215-2df7f4b2de41>", line 1, in <lambda>
    answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: sum(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].str.contains(x)))

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 1562, in contains
    regex=regex)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py", line 254, in str_contains
    stacklevel=3)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\warnings.py", line 99, in _showwarnmsg
    msg.file, msg.line)

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1069, in _showwarning
    file.write(formatWarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\utils.py", line 69, in formatWarning
    file = filename.replace("/", "\\").rsplit("\\", 1)[1] # find the file name

IndexError: list index out of range
```

## update

I modified my code and removed all special character from the `Value` column. I am still getting the error...what could be wrong.
Even with the error, the new column gets added to my `answer2` dataframe

```
answer2=answer[['Value','non_repeat_pdf']]

print(answer2)

             Value                                     non_repeat_pdf
0              law    Initials: __\nDL_  -1- Date: __\n8/14/2017\n...
1        concerned                                                   
2           rights                                                   
3                c                                                   
4          violate                                                   
5                8                                                   
6        agreement                                                   
7           voting                                                   
8       previously                                                   
9      supervisory                                                   
10             its                                                   
11        exercise                                                   
12            occs                                                   
13        entities                                                   
14           those                                                   
15        approved                                                   
16          1818h2                                                   
17               9                                                   
18             are                                                   
19          manner                                                   
20           their                                                   
21         affairs                                                   
22               b                                                   
23         solicit                                                   
24         procure                                                   
25        transfer                                                   
26         attempt                                                   
27      extraneous                                                   
28    modification                                                   
29            vote                                                   
           ...                                                ...
1552       closing                                                   
1553       heavily                                                   
1554            pm                                                   
1555    throughout                                                   
1556          half                                                   
1557        window                                                   
1558   sixtysecond                                                   
1559      activity                                                   
1560      sampling                                                   
1561         using                                                   
1562          hour                                                   
1563      violated                                                   
1564          euro                                                   
1565         rates                                                   
1566   derivatives                                                   
1567    portfolios                                                   
1568     valuation                                                   
1569       parties                                                   
1570      numerous                                                   
1571          they                                                   
1572     reference                                                   
1573       because                                                   
1574            us                                                   
1575     important                                                   
1576        moment                                                   
1577      snapshot                                                   
1578           cet                                                   
1579           215                                                   
1580       finance                                                   
1581   supervision                                                   

[1582 rows x 2 columns]

answer2['found_in_all_PDF'] = answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].tolist()).count(x))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-298-4dc80361895c>", line 1, in <module>
    answer2['found_in_all_PDF'] = answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].tolist()).count(x))

  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2331, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)

  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2404, in _set_item
    self._check_setitem_copy()

  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1873, in _check_setitem_copy
    warnings.warn(t, SettingWithCopyWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)

  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\warnings.py", line 99, in _showwarnmsg
    msg.file, msg.line)

  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1069, in _showwarning
    file.write(formatWarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))

  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\utils.py", line 69, in formatWarning
    file = filename.replace("/", "\\").rsplit("\\", 1)[1] # find the file name

IndexError: list index out of range
```

## update2

below works

```
answer2=answer[['Value','non_repeat_pdf']]

xyz= answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].tolist()).count(x))
xyz=xyz.to_frame()
xyz.columns=['found_in_all_PDF']
pd.concat([answer2, xyz], axis=1)
Out[305]: 
             Value                                     non_repeat_pdf  \
0              law    Initials: __\nDL_  -1- Date: __\n8/14/2017\n...   
1        concerned                                                      
2           rights                                                      
3                c                                                      
4          violate                                                      
5                8                                                      
6        agreement                                                      
7           voting                                                      
8       previously                                                      
9      supervisory                                                      
10             its                                                      
11        exercise                                                      
12            occs                                                      
13        entities                                                      
14           those                                                      
15        approved                                                      
16          1818h2                                                      
17               9                                                      
18             are                                                      
19          manner                                                      
20           their                                                      
21         affairs                                                      
22               b                                                      
23         solicit                                                      
24         procure                                                      
25        transfer                                                      
26         attempt                                                      
27      extraneous                                                      
28    modification                                                      
29            vote                                                      
           ...                                                ...   
1552       closing                                                      
1553       heavily                                                      
1554            pm                                                      
1555    throughout                                                      
1556          half                                                      
1557        window                                                      
1558   sixtysecond                                                      
1559      activity                                                      
1560      sampling                                                      
1561         using                                                      
1562          hour                                                      
1563      violated                                                      
1564          euro                                                      
1565         rates                                                      
1566   derivatives                                                      
1567    portfolios                                                      
1568     valuation                                                      
1569       parties                                                      
1570      numerous                                                      
1571          they                                                      
1572     reference                                                      
1573       because                                                      
1574            us                                                      
1575     important                                                      
1576        moment                                                      
1577      snapshot                                                      
1578           cet                                                      
1579           215                                                      
1580       finance                                                      
1581   supervision                                                      

      found_in_all_PDF  
0                    6  
1                    1  
2                    4  
3                 1036  
4                    9  
5                   93  
6                    4  
7                    2  
8                    1  
9                    2  
10                   6  
11                   1  
12                   0  
13                   1  
14                   3  
15                   1  
16                   0  
17                  25  
18                  20  
19                   3  
20                  14  
21                   4  
22                 358  
23                   2  
24                   1  
25                   2  
26                   6  
27                   1  
28                   1  
29                   3  
               ...  
1552                 3  
1553                 2  
1554                 0  
1555                 5  
1556                 2  
1557                 3  
1558                 0  
1559                 2  
1560                 1  
1561                 5  
1562                 2  
1563                 7  
1564                 8  
1565                 3  
1566                 0  
1567                 1  
1568                 1  
1569                 4  
1570                 1  
1571                 9  
1572                 2  
1573                 2  
1574                96  
1575                 1  
1576                 1  
1577                 1  
1578                 0  
1579                 0  
1580                 1  
1581                 0  

[1582 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: 1. I can`t reproduce error. If you want me to look on you error share a dataset and describe your environment, like python, pandas, numpy  versions.  

2. On general your toy code looks slightly ineffective:
2.1 Why you concatenate on every step (1582 times) all rows in ''non_repeat_pdf"  - do it one time before.
2.2. ''non_repeat_pdf" looks huge, maybe concatenation on 1582 of them is to huge and that gives error?

3. What is you goal? maybe there some other approaches to do that?

Comment: 2. how would you change my toy code?

Comment: at list `s = ''.join(df['URL'].tolist())
df['found_in_column'] = df['Jan'].apply(lambda x,s: s.count(x),s=s)
`

Comment: Look like you have a dictionary in "Value" and corpus in "non_repeat_pdf" . Could be "non_repeat_pdf" tokenized to "Value" like by str.split(' ')?

Comment: They are two columns. I create `Value` column by `['pdf_text'].str.split(' ', expand=True)` and then melting the dataframe...how does that affect the above code?

Comment: [str.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)
will do the same and will count values entrance in 'pdf_text'. if 'non_repeat_pdf' is a version of 'pdf_text' it will solve your task.

Comment: but in any case, why does update gives error and update2 works?

Comment: Because inside it works differently. I could only guess that when creating thousands of times an extremely long string can cause some difficulties in the garbage collector and they can manifest themselves differently in different contexts.

Comment: in such case, can i use method shown in update2 to add the columns? do you see any problems with thtat? thanks for replies by the way

Comment: Well, if it works and performance is not a problem, why not use:). I may be to old, but adding the complexity of _o (N*N)_ to the algorithm just to save one line of code drives me crazy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i can't reproduce exactly same error on my environment. But what I see is warning about wrong regexp usage. Your string was interpreted as capturing regular expression because of brackets in the string `"1818(e);"`. Try use [str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)  with `regex=False`.

```py
answer2 =pd.DataFrame({'Value': {11: '1818(e);'}, 'non_repeat_pdf': {11: '@@@@'}})
answer2['Value'].apply(lambda x: sum(answer2['non_repeat_pdf'].str.contains(x,regex=False)))
```

Output:

```py
11    0
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: i tried few more things and updated the question. Please help